# How to align different parts of an equation to left or right?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

For my homework I am required to replicate (among other things) the following equation:

[image]

I was able to achieve this using `align`:

```
\begin{align*}
    some stuff with & \tag{15} \\
            & some  other stuff & \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad \; 0 < x < 1. 
\end{align*}
```

but I had to use 4 `\qquad`'s because the part on the right would not be on the right! This is ugly, but what bothers me more is the fact that `align` had worked before for this equation:

[image]

I used the following code here:

```
\begin{align*}
    foo &= bar \tag{15} \\
        &baz \\
    foo &= bar \\
        & baz & 0 < x < 1,
\end{align*}
```

You can see that the part on the right sits exactly where it should without using an embarrassing amount of `\quad`s.

How do make those this equation align properly? How do I make a part of a line flush to the right?

Just for reference, this is how my PDF looks with the code above (this is from *Bateman Manuscript Project*, *Higher Transcendental Functions* [vol. I](http://apps.nrbook.com/bateman/Vol1.pdf), p. 23):

[image]

---

Here is my full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article} %leqno is to align equation labels to left

\usepackage[bottom=0in, top=0.4in, left=1.2in, right=1.2in]{geometry} % set margins to look like the original
\usepackage{xfrac, relsize,fancyhdr} % for slanted fractions, bigger integral signs, and some other things
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} % for equations flushed to left, among other things
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac} % for nice slanted fractions

\DeclareMathOperator{\csch}{csch}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % removes default page number
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % removes the top line

\headheight=15pt % smaller header height was yielding warnings in pdflatex compiler
\fancyhead[C]{GAMMA FUNCTION} % adds header
\voffset=0.15in % header position


\begin{document}

\rhead{23} % ads page number as a header
\lhead{\textbf{1.9.1}} 

\noindent \textbf{1.9.1. \; Kummer's series for } \textbf{$\log \Gamma (z)$} \\

The function $\log \Gamma (x)$, $0 < x < 1$, can be expanded in a Fourier series. We shall use the known Fourier expansions (Bromwich, 1947, pp. 356, 393, and 370 respectively):
\begin{align*}
    & \log(\sin\pi x) =  -  \log 2  -  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \, (1/n) \cos (2\pi n x), \\
    & \csch (\nicefrac{1}{2} \, t) \, \sinh (\nicefrac{1}{2}-x)t = 8 \pi \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} [n \; \sin(2\pi n x)]/(t^2 + 4{\pi}^2 n^2), \\
    & \pi (1 - 2x) = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1/n) \sin(2 \pi nx).
\end{align*}

If these are substituted in (7) with $z=x$, we have to evaluate the integral 

\[\mathlarger{\int_0^{\infty}} \left(\frac{2\pi n}{t^2 + 4{\pi}^2 \, n^2)} - \frac{e^{-t}}{2\pi n} \right)\frac{dt}{t} = \frac{1}{2\pi n} \mathlarger{\int_0^{\infty}} \left(\frac{1}{1+t^2} - e^{-2 \pi n t}\right)\frac{dt}{t}\]

\[= \frac{1}{2 \pi n} \left[ \mathlarger{\int_0^\infty} \left( \frac{1}{1+t^2}-\cos t \right) \frac{dt}{t} + \mathlarger{\int_0^\infty} \frac{e^{-t}-e^{-2 \pi n t}}{t}dt + \mathlarger{\int_0^\infty}(\cos t - e^{-t})\frac{dt}{t}\right]\] \\

\noindent and by means of 1.7(21) and 1.7(18) this is $(2 \pi n)^{-1}[\gamma + \log(2 \pi n)]$ since we have for the third integral: \\

$\lim \limits_{\delta \, \to \, 0} \, \int_\delta^{\, \infty} \, (\cos t - e^{-t}) \, t^{-1} dt = \lim \limits_{\delta \to 0} \; [\, \text{Ei}(- \delta) - \text{Ci} (\delta) \,] = 0.$ \\

\noindent Thus we have
\begin{align*}
    \log \, \Gamma(x) &= \nicefrac{1}{2} \log(2 \pi) \tag{14}\\
                      &+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty [(2 \pi)^{-1} \, \cos(2 \pi n x) + (\gamma + \log 2 \pi n) \, (\pi n)^{-1} \, \sin(2 \pi n x)], \\
    \log \, \Gamma(x) &= (\nicefrac{1}{2}-x)(\gamma + \log 2) + (1-x) \, \log \pi - \nicefrac{1}{2} \log(\sin \pi x)\\
                      &+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\pi n)^{-1} \log n \, \sin(2 \pi n x) & 0 < x < 1,
\end{align*} 

\noindent which is Kummer's series.

A similar representation for $\psi (x)$ is due to Lerch (Nielsen, 1906, p. 204),
\begin{align*}
    \psi (x)&  \, \sin(\pi x) = - \nicefrac{1}{2} \pi \cos(\pi x) - (\gamma + \log 2 \pi) \sin \pi x \tag{15} \\
            &+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \log \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right) \sin(2 \pi + 1) \pi x & \, & \; 0 < x < 1.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `2` alignment groups require `3` &. That said, what you want to achieve is not very clear.

Comment: Like what? I just tried inserting another `&` but the thing is still not aligned properly.

Comment: Could you post a full compilable code, and explain a little more? It seems you want equation numbering on the left?

Comment: Yes, I achieved that with `leqno`. I can post the code, but it's 64 lines - wouldn't it be too much a mess?

Comment: Not really a problem, we'll extract  a relevant fraction if necessary.

Comment: Done. Hope my instructor doesn't kill me for this :P

Comment: It's a `latex` homework?

Comment: Yes, I have to replicate a certain page in LaTeX. I don't think this is going to be a problem, since I've already done most of the work.

Comment: The main point for me is you learn some tricks.

Comment: I can't begin to count how many tricks I've learned :D

Answer (score 2):

Here is my (honest) proposal. I'm not sure I've understood what you want to obtain in full detail, but I did what seemed sensible. In particular, I removed most  manual spacings, and defined a macro for the larger integrals, which not include the bounds, but require a manual correction for the placement of the lower bound. Note I gave different alignments for the second lines in eqs 14 and 15, to show the possibilities.

```
 \documentclass[12pt, leqno]{article} %leqno is to allgn equation labels to left

\usepackage[bottom=0in, top=0.55in,hmargin=1.2in, headheight=15pt, showframe]{geometry} % set margins to look like the original
\usepackage{xfrac, relsize,fancyhdr} % for slanted fractions, bigger integral signs, and some other things
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools, nccmath} % for equations flushed to left, among other things
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac} % for nice slanted fractions

\DeclareMathOperator{\csch}{csch}

\pagestyle{fancy} % I'm not really sure what this does, but the internet guys said to use it ¯ \ _ (ツ) _ / ¯
\fancyhf{} % removes default page number
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % removes the top line


\fancyhead[C]{GAMMA FUNCTION} % adds header

\newcommand\lint{\mathop{\mathlarger{\int}}\nolimits}

\begin{document}

\rhead{23} % adds page number as a header
\lhead{\textbf{1.9.1}}

\noindent \textbf{1.9.1. \; Kummer's series for \boldmath$\log \Gamma (z)$}\bigskip

The function $\log \Gamma (x)$, $0 < x < 1$, can be expanded in a Fourier series. We shall use the known Fourier expansions (Bromwich, 1947, pp. 356, 393, and 370 respectively):
\begin{align*}
    & \log(\sin\pi x) = - \log 2 - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \, (1/n) \cos (2\pi n x), \\
    & \csch (\mfrac{1}{2} \, t) \, \sinh (\mfrac{1}{2}-x)t = 8 \pi \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} [n \; \sin(2\pi n x)]/(t^2 + 4{\pi }^2 n^2), \\
    & \pi (1 - 2x) = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1/n) \sin(2 \pi nx).
\end{align*}

If these are substituted in (7) with $z=x$, we have to evaluate the integral
%
\begin{multline*}
    \lint_{\mkern-15mu 0}^{\infty} \biggl(\frac{2\pi n}{t^2 + 4{\pi }^2 \, n^2)} - \frac{e^{-t}}{2\pi n} \biggr)\frac{dt}{t} = \frac{1}{2\pi n} \lint_{\mkern-15mu 0}^{\infty}\biggl(\frac{1}{1+t^2} - e^{-2 \pi n t}\biggr)\frac{dt}{t} \\
     = \frac{1}{2 \pi n} \left[ \lint_{\mkern-15mu 0}^\infty \biggl( \frac{1}{1+t^2}-\cos t \biggr) \frac{dt}{t}
     + \lint_{\mkern-15mu 0}^\infty \frac{e^{-t}-e^{-2 \pi n t}}{t}dt %
     + \lint_{\mkern-15mu 0}^\infty (\cos t - e^{-t})\frac{dt}{t}\right]
\end{multline*}%
and by means of 1.7(21) and 1.7(18) this is $(2 \pi n)^{-1}[\gamma + \log(2 \pi n)]$ since we have for the third integral:
%
\[ \lim_{\delta \to 0} \int_\delta^{\infty}(\cos t - e^{-t}) \, t^{-1} dt = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \bigl [\text{Ei}(- \delta ) - \text{Ci} (\delta ) \bigr] = 0. \]
%
 Thus we have
\begin{flalign} \tag{14}
\log \Gamma (x) &= \begin{aligned}[t] & \nicefrac{1}{2} \log(2 \pi ) & \\
& \mathrlap{+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty [(2 \pi )^{-1} \, \cos(2 \pi n x) + (\gamma + \log 2 \pi n) \, (\pi n)^{-1} \, \mathrlap{\sin(2 \pi n x)]},}
\end{aligned} &
\\
\notag
\log \Gamma (x) &= \begin{aligned}[t] & (\nicefrac{1}{2}-x)(\gamma + \log 2) + { (1-x) \, \log \pi -\nicefrac{1}{2} \log(\sin \pi x)}\\
&+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\pi n)^{-1} \log n \, \sin(2 \pi n x)
\end{aligned} %
& & \begin{aligned}[t]
& \mbox{}\\[2ex] 0 < x < 1, \end{aligned}
\end{flalign}
%
which is Kummer's series.

A similar representation for $\psi (x)$ is due to Lerch (Nielsen, 1906, p. 204),%
\begin{flalign}\tag{15}%
    \psi (x)\sin(\pi x)&= - \nicefrac{1}{2} \pi \cos(\pi x) - (\gamma + \log 2 \pi ) \sin \pi x \\
     & + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \log \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right) \sin(2 \pi + 1) \pi x % This is ugly, but there's nothing I could do
     & & 0 < x < 1.\notag
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is weird - it is still [not left enough when I compile it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkJ4k.png)

Comment: What should be more to the left? The equation numbers are at the left margin. I don't see what you mean.  Equation numbers in the left margin, and body of the equation beginning at the left margin?

Comment: Sorry :D I meant __right__. `0<x<1.` should be on the right, directly under  `0<x<1,` in (14). It is correct on your render, but not on mine.

Comment: @Gallifreyan: I have a solution with the `flalign` environment. That's the first I thought of, but it seemed to be conflicting with the `leqno` option –  probably some bug of `amsmath`. However, loading `mathtools` (which fixes some of these bugs) in the place of amsmath solves the problem. Please see my updated answer. Is it more like you want?

Comment: I used `\hspace` from your previous revision along with `\align` and it worked like a charm! Thanks for all the other stuff though, I'll use it in my next assignments  :)

Comment: With the latest version you don't have to find the value for `\hspace` (more or less by trial and error:`flalign` makes it automatic.

Comment: Oooh, I see now - it works with `\mathtools`! Definitely what I was looking for!

Comment: The two `0<x<1` items don't seem to be at the same horizontal position -- is this deliberate?

Comment: @Mico: No. I've modified my initial version, because I had a correct alignment, but the equation number was on the 2ndline, and I forgot to check all details in the new version. There seems to be a conflict with the option `[t]` or `b]` for aligned. I'll investigate for a solution. Thank you for pointing the problem!

Comment: Maybe the code that's currently posted is out of sync? To wit, when I run your code, equation number "14" is far to the left of the left margin and the first `0<x<1` qualifier isn't flush with the right-hand edge of the text block.

Comment: @Mico: Problem solved. Just add a second ampersand on the first line of `flalign`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another attempt. Note that I've tried to make the code more "LaTeX-y" by using instructions such as `\subsubsection` and letting LaTeX place left-aligned equation numbers. I've gotten rid of the `\mathlarger` instructions (they're not needed) as well as of most instances of `\,` (thinspace) -- let TeX take care of the appropriate spacing before and after math operators. I've replaced the two instances of `\lim\limits` with just `\lim` (the `\limits` directives aren't needed). I don't think `\nicefrac{1}{2}` looks good, at least not with Computer Modern; I recommend using `\tfrac` instead. I've replaced all instances of `\left` and `\right` with `\biggl` and `\biggr`, resp. I've gotten rid of the super-kludgy `\voffset=0.15in` directive and, instead, added the option `includehead` while loading `geometry`. Eliminating almost all blank lines also permits omitting most `\noindent` directives. Finally, I've used `\mkern` directives to position the `0<x<1` terms.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage[bottom=0in,top=0.4in,hmargin=1.2in,
   includehead]{geometry} 
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
   \DeclareMathOperator{\csch}{csch}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,indentfirst} 
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   \fancyhf{} 
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
   \headheight=15pt 
   \chead{GAMMA FUNCTION} 
   \rhead{\arabic{page}}  % page number 
   \lhead{\thesubsubsection} 


\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{subsection}{9}
\setcounter{page}{23}
\setcounter{equation}{13}

\begin{document}
% insert `\boldmath` directive in arg. of '\subsubsection` if '\log\Gamma' should be bolded 
\subsubsection{Kummer's series for $\log \Gamma (z)$} 

The function $\log \Gamma (x)$, $0 < x < 1$, can be expanded in 
a Fourier series. We shall use the known Fourier expansions 
(Bromwich, 1947, pp.\ 356, 393, and 370 respectively):
\begin{align*}
    & \log(\sin\pi x) =  -\log2 -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/n)\cos(2\pi nx), \\
    & \csch(\tfrac{1}{2}t)\sinh(\tfrac{1}{2}-x)t 
      = 8\pi\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} [n\sin(2\pi nx)]/(t^2 + 4\pi^2 n^2), \\
    & \pi(1-2x) = 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/n)\sin(2\pi nx).
\end{align*}

If these are substituted in (7) with $z=x$, we have to evaluate 
the integral 
\begin{multline*}
\int_0^{\infty} \biggl( \frac{2\pi n}{t^2 + 4\pi^2 n^2} - \frac{e^{-t}}{2\pi n} \biggr)\frac{dt}{t} 
= \frac{1}{2\pi n} \int_0^{\infty} \biggl(\frac{1}{1+t^2} - e^{-2 \pi nt}\biggr)\frac{dt}{t}\\
= \frac{1}{2 \pi n} \Biggl[ \int_0^\infty \biggl( \frac{1}{1+t^2}-\cos t \biggr) \frac{dt}{t} 
+ \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}-e^{-2\pi nt}}{t}\,dt 
+ \int_0^\infty(\cos t - e^{-t})\frac{dt}{t}\Biggr]
\end{multline*}
and by means of 1.7(21) and 1.7(18) this is 
$(2\pi n)^{-1}[\gamma+\log(2\pi n)]$ 
since we have for the third integral: 
\[
\lim_{\delta\to 0} \int_\delta^{\infty}  (\cos t-e^{-t}) t^{-1}\, dt = 
\lim_{\delta\to 0} \,[ \text{Ei}(-\delta) - \text{Ci}(\delta)] = 0\,.
\]
Thus we have 
\begin{align}
\log\Gamma(x) &= \tfrac{1}{2} \log(2 \pi) \\
\notag    &+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty [(2\pi)^{-1}\cos(2\pi n x) 
          + (\gamma+\log2\pi n)(\pi n)^{-1}\sin(2\pi nx)], \\
\log\Gamma(x) &= (\tfrac{1}{2}-x)(\gamma+\log2)+(1-x)  
           \log\pi-\tfrac{1}{2}\log(\sin\pi x)\notag\\
\notag   &+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty(\pi n)^{-1}\log n  \sin(2\pi nx) &  \mkern16mu 0 < x < 1, 
\end{align} 
which is Kummer's series.

A similar representation for $\psi(x)$ 
is due to Lerch (Nielsen, 1906, p.\ 204),
\begin{align}
\psi (x)& \sin(\pi x) = -\tfrac{1}{2} \pi\cos(\pi x) 
          - (\gamma+\log2\pi)\sin\pi x \\
\notag  &+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \log \biggl( \frac{n}{n+1} \biggr) 
          \sin(2\pi+1) \pi x & \mkern145mu 0 < x < 1. 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The original clearly doesn't use `\boldmath` in the section title. The section/subsection number can be added at the top left by suitably redefining `\sectionmark` and `\subsectionmark`.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. I was looking at the original more closely just now and had also noticed some of these issues. I'll provide suitable updates shortly.

Comment: @egreg no no no no, this is exactly how this stuff appears in the book! I used `\textbf` but it didn't work on formulae

Comment: @Gallifreyan - If you really need math material in the sectioning header to be in bold (and I don't think it's required here), insert `\boldmath` in the argument of `\subsubsection`.

Comment: I didn't want to have to deal with subsections for now, so I left it as it is and used `\bm`, since `\boldmath` bolded all math in the document. But thanks for `\setcount`, I think I'll have a use for it in the future!

Comment: @Gallifreyan - In the (hopefully not entirely vain) hope that you'll learn a few things about LaTeX and its programmability from this exercise, I deliberately provided a bit of material that shows how to make use of LaTeX's machinery. In the short run (i.e., for your assignment), this may well seem like more work than simply engaging in visual formatting. In the longer run, though, I think (hope?) you'll appreciate knowing a few LaTeX-related programming tricks.

Comment: Given I am a Physics major, I don't think I have a choice but to learn LaTeX in full :D